# urls with ajax calls in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm clicking on a button on a users page localhost:3000/users1 in my Rails application, which triggers an ajax call. The url specified in the ajax code is `game_start`. However, Rails is prefixing the 'users' onto that url, like this `/users/game_start` when it makes the ajax request, so that in routes.rb I have to do `match '/users/game_start' => 'gamecontroller#start'` to make it work.  Is this expected behavior? Why is it attaching `/users/` onto the url?

```
$.ajax({
          url: "game_start",
          data: { user: data },  
          type: "POST",
          success: function(response) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing your ajax call manually, I suggest adding a heading slash to the url, like this

```
url: "/game_start"
```

Comment: that seems to have been the problem. Thanks